# How to make curved corner collapsing toolbar in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, rounded-corners

How to make curve corner for collapsing toolbar while scrolling

What I am Expecting is

[image]

What I am Getting is

[image]

Note the image is scrollable and inside collapsing toolbar

Code is given below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_coordinate_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:outlineProvider="background">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:outlineProvider="background"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
                app:title="Image"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapseCollapsedStyle"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapseExpandedStyle"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:outlineProvider="background">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/material_tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.75"
                    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                    android:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coffee_img"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:src="@drawable/coffee"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="12dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Image"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:background="@drawable/light_grey_curved_bg"/>


            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <include
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                layout="@layout/common_circular_back_button"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <include
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                layout="@layout/like_button_with_loader"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"/>
                
            </LinearLayout>
            
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Everything working fine the curved corner of `imageview` reflect but while scrolling to the the to the curved corner apply only for the bottom corner. Top corner of the image gets rectangle shape

Is it possible to curve the corner of the collapsing toolbar android?